# How to remove duplicate data values from an array of objects in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, underscore.js, array-filter

I want to be able to use **array methods** or some other form of javascript processing without any **external javascript library** in order to iterate through a multi dimensional array and remove any duplicate values. Here is an example below:

```js
var places = [{
    "category": "other",
    "title": "harry University",
    "value": 4788,
    "id": "1"
  },
  {
    "category": "traveling",
    "title": "tommy University",
    "value": 5460,
    "id": "2"
  },
  {
    "category": "education",
    "title": "jerry University",
    "value": 7853456,
    "id": "3"
  },
  {
    "category": "business",
    "title": "Charlie University",
    "value": 6779589,
    "id": "4"
  },
  {
    "category": "business",
    "title": "NYU",
    "value": 0117824,
    "id": "5"
  }
];
```

I have tried to use `array.filter` to remove the duplicate `category` values but the approach I have taken does not work.

Here is my code

```js
places = places.map(JSON.stringify).reverse()
  .filter(function(item, index, places) {
    return places.indexOf(item, index + 1) === -1;
  })
  .reverse().map(JSON.parse)
console.log(places)
```

The above doesn't work because it is operating on the whole array so the data does not change.

When I use a library like **underscore.js** they have a method that works

```js
let newPlaces = [];
_.each(_.uniq(_.pluck(places, "category")), function(category) {
  newPlaces.push(_.findWhere(places, {
    category: category
  }));
});
console.log(newPlaces);
```

But I want to be able to use `.filter` or some other vanilla javascript method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example is not a multidimensional array. But simply a regular array of objects. A multi-dimensional array would be something like `let a = [[1],[1]];` which is an array of arrays. Anyway, are you looking to simply remove all objects(items in the array) for which a category has already appeared once. You can do this with the Vanilla Javascript filter method like you wanted. You simply have to use an object to keep count of whether the object has appeared before or not.
Here is a simple approach

```js
function removeDuplicates(arrToBeFiltered, keyToMatch){
  let dups = {};
  return arrToBeFiltered.filter(function(item){ 
    if(item[keyToMatch] in dups){return false;} 
    else {
        dups[item[keyToMatch]] = true; return true;
    }}); 
}
places = removeDuplicates(places,'category');
```

Comment: I am using yours because I want to use the array filter method which you are using. And I changed the title of this question. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Simple for Loop. Just call `DeDupPlaces` with the array and a string filter.

```js
const DeDupPlaces = (arrToBefiltered, filter) => {
  const seen = [];
  const result = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < arrToBefiltered.length; i++) {
    const filterValue = arrToBefiltered[i][filter];

    if(!seen.includes(filterValue)){
        seen.push(filterValue);
        result.push(arrToBefiltered[i]);
    }
  }
  return result;
}
DeDupPlaces(places, 'category');
```

[JS Fiddle with your example](https://jsfiddle.net/Twiggeh99/rbzv9m2n/12/)